# Overlay navbar, rather than push page contents, on expand

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap 4.0, I want to overlay the navbar above the contents of a page, rather than push the contents down, when the navbar expands from the collapsed state after clicking the hamburger.

I've tried setting a z-index property on the navbar class and several others. Also tried to put a wrapper around the nav element and set z-index: 1000 and position: absolute on that. So far I haven't managed. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `fixed-top` class to your navbar.

When using a `fixed-top` navbar, your `<body>` element needs a `padding-top` property equal to the height of the navbar (normally `70px` - but can differ based on the theme).

The above is also true for `fixed-bottom` navbars (at the bottom end).